# Attachments encoded using different encoding schemes in single email

Tags: email, encoding, email-attachments

Attachments in an email can be encoded.

1. What are the methods/techniques available for attachment encoding?
2. In a single email containing multiple attachments, can we encode different attachments through different encoding techniques (using any email client or some programming)?

Comment: From tripleee's answer, Igot better understanding of attachment encoding. Updating my question.

Answer (score 0):

Out of those three, only MIME is properly standardized and widely supported. The legacy encodings (BinHex and uuencode) are mainly there for backwards compatibility. They used to have competition (xxencode etc) but since no official standard existed before MIME, it's not really possible to provide an exhaustive answer.

I don't know what to call these things - the document you link to calls them "methods", not "encodings".

The term "encoding" in modern usage would primarily refer to the content-transfer encoding, i. e. in MIME either base64 or quoted-printable.

I would not mix these "methods" in a single message; in fact, I find it hard to imagine a situation where you would choose anything but MIME unless you are heavily burdened with supporting obsolescent systems. The older methods are basically just untyped text/plain data in the middle of other text/plain data, so it is fathomable that a uudecode application could pick up BinHex data and complain, crash, and/or produce incorrect output, and vice versa.